# Cucumber: how to define a string with only letters as the Given

Tags: java, regex, cucumber

I am working on Cucumber framework, and I have written my feature file and run the test runner. From that I got the snippets, which have to be implemented. I am a bit confused with one as the scenario is that a user types a non-digits string e.g. `"nonumbers"`.

```
@Given("The string contains {string}")
public void the_string_contains(String string) {

}
```

As I am unable to just say `string = "^[a-zA-Z]+$";` I am not sure how I should define the string as a non-digits string. As it is the `@Given`, I am not using `Pattern` in order to check if the string is correctly formated

Comment: `^\D+$` will match non digits.

Comment: check my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/) you can use `{string}` to match single-quoted or double-quoted strings, for example `"banana split"` or `'banana split'` (but not `banana split`). Only the text between the quotes will be extracted. The quotes themselves are discarded.
Note that Cucumber expressions (like `{string}`) are available as of Cucumber-jvm v3.x

Answer (score 0):

For my feature file I did the following implementation. Please check the screenshot:

**Feature file**
[image]

**Java file**
[image]

With the above implementation everything executed just fine.